# WPF Detecting Window Close Event and coupling with a button event

Tags: c#, wpf, button, event-handling

For two days, I have tried various methods for making it so that on loadButton click, it opens a secondary window and disables the loadButton; Then, when that secondary window has been closed, the loadButton will be re-enabled. Although, obviously all of my attempts have been unsucessful.

I have been reading about using the isClosing event, although, I haven't figured out how to properly implement it. So I decided to go with this route.

```
private void loadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var richWindow = RichTextWindow.GetWindow(new RichTextWindow());


    if (richWindow.IsActive != true)
    {
        loadButton.IsEnabled = false;
        richWindow.Show();
    }
     else
    {
        loadButton.IsEnabled = true;
    }         
}
```

Issue here is, the first half is executed. Once I click the loadButton, it does disable. However, on closing the new Window, the loadButton is still disabled.
Could anyone point me in the right direction on where I need to go with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
private void loadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var richWindow = RichTextWindow.GetWindow(new RichTextWindow());
    richWindow.Closed += (s, e) => loadButton.IsEnabled = true;
    loadButton.IsEnabled = false;
    richWindow.Show();
}
```

Basically, disable the button before opening the window. Then, listen for the window to close and enable the button again.

Comment: This is a lambda expression right? However, in order to get it to work inside the click event, I did have to change the (s, e) to (s, ex), otherwise it would have changed the meaning of "e" according to the debugger. 
However, it does work the way I envisioned the original outcome to be. So I thank you.

Comment: Yes it is a lambda expression. It is the same as registering a private callback method as the event handler, just done inline as an anonymous method for simplicity. I didn't notice the conflicting variable name, but you can name it whatever you want (it isn't used anyways). The delegate for the method is [EventHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
richWindow.Loaded +=
{
     loadedButton.IsEnabled = false;
 };

richWindow.Closing +=
{
    loadedButton.IsEnabled = true;
 }
```